# getting Server logs with Node express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to get response from a particular server which I know. data is logged in the server. how can I get this logged data with NodeJS and maybe `console.log` the response.

I have not done this before and I have no idea how to get data from the server. I am used to using express `app.get`

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info? Does the server has an endpoint exposing that data? The data logged by the server is stored in files, in a database which you want to access?

Comment: the data is just logged in a file. it a tracker log

Comment: And you want to retrieve that file from the server?

Comment: yes pass it in like `app.get('/opt/traccar/logs/tracker-server.log', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`REs ${res}`)
    console.log(`REQ ${req}`)
})`

Comment: I see. The file with all the logs is in the same server running the nodejs application? In that case you can use fs to read the file and do a console.log of the content or send the content in a response.

Comment: currently the node application is still on my local machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193644/discussion-between-ale-sanchez-and-king).